# I can't align my components horizontally using React and CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm having some problems lining up some React Bootstrap cards, the only way I could align them horizontally was by putting them both inside a div, but I need a component for each card, if I ran the code that way, it would end up going wrong

[image: How the application is now]

[image: And I needed it stays like this]

Basically, every time I add a card, it's aligned vertically, not horizontally.

**HostingCard.tsx**

```
import { Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./App.css";

export default function HostingCard() {
  return (
      <div className="main">
        <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
          <Card.Img variant="top" src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>
              Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
              bulk of the card's content.
            </Card.Text>
            <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**App.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import HostingCard from "./HostingCard";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <h1 style={{ padding: "1rem" }}>Hospedagens</h1>
      <HostingCard />
      <HostingCard />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**App.css**

```
 .main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0.1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Normally you'd build a Bootstrap grid in your app component and loop through your cards with a column for each. You wouldn't have a stack of individual components in your markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flexDirection: row` applies to the children *inside* the row. You're creating a column of rows where each row contains only one item in each.

For the row to work as a row it needs to be a **container** for the cards, something like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <h1 style={{ padding: "1rem" }}>Hospedagens</h1>
      <div style={{ flexDirection: 'row', /* ...more styles */ }}>
        <HostingCard />
        <HostingCard />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

Since you're already using React Bootstrap, you can browse its Layout docs and choose something suitable that they already built instead of styling your own div.

[**Horizontal Stack**](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/stack/) looks like what you want:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <h1 style={{ padding: "1rem" }}>Hospedagens</h1>
      <Stack direction="horizontal" gap={4}>
        <HostingCard />
        <HostingCard />
      </Stack>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Look at its implementation and you'll see it's ultimately a `div` container with `flexDirection: row` plus a bunch of additional preset options and styles.